# Posting when offline (React-Native)

Tags: database, react-native, save, cloud, offline

I am currently doing a project in which I need to implement a logic when the user posts when offline. For ex. when a user goes offline and he presses Save(to a database on cloud), I don't want those data to be lost, I want those data to be saved as soon as the connection is back.
I have not found anything specific even after hours of search.
Thank you for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [NetInfo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo) to check connection status, then if the user is offline, you can store their post using [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage). Once `NetInfo` has detected that the device is online again, it can pull from `AsyncStorage` any posts that were saved, upload them, and clear their keys.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I will try it!

Comment: If my answer helped, please select it as the best answer 

Comment: I havent tried it yet, but ok I will mark it as the best answer :)